# How to build a perl web-service infrastructure

Tags: web-services, perl

I have many scripts that I use to manage a multi server infrastructure.  Some of these scripts require root access, some require access to a databases, and most of them are perl based.  I would like to convert all these scripts into very simple web services that can be executed from different applications.  These web services would take regular request inputs and would output json as a result of being executed.  I'm thinking that I should setup a simple perl dispatcher, call it `action`, that would do logging, checking credentials, and executing these simple scripts.  Something like:

```
http://host/action/update-dns?server=www.google.com&ip=192.168.1.1
```

This would invoke the `action` perl driver which in turn would call the `update-dns` script with the appropriate parameters (perhaps cleaned in some way) and return an appropriate json response.  I would like for this infrastructure to have the following attributes:

- All scripts reside in a single place.  If a new script is dropped there, then it automatically becomes callable.
- All scripts need to have some form of manifest that describe, who can call it (belonging to some ldap group), what parameters does it take, what is the response, etc.  So that it is self explained.
- All scripts are logged in terms of who did what and what was the response.
- It would be great if there was a command line way to do something like `# action update-dns --server=www.google.com --up=192.168.1.1`

Do I have to get this going from scratch or is there something already on top of which I can piggy back on?

Comment: how about using a combination of http://java.net/projects/hudson/ and http://www.nagios.org/ either a perfect match or completely off ;-)

Comment: @Fredrik will take a look at this.  I'm looking for something simple and lightweight, preferably perl based.

Comment: as Fredrik recommends, nagios is worth a look. As the [nagios plug.ins](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins) are separate executables, many of them written in C and Perl, they can be used even without nagios tself. You can be use them in your own application (wrt license), if you reinvent/modify the wheel.

Comment: The server infrastructure is already controlled by nagios.  It works great for monitoring what is going on.  What I would really like to do is to provision a new server using these web services, update their dns entries, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out my framework [Sub::Spec](http://p3rl.org/Sub%3a%3aSpec). The documentation is still sparse, but I'm already using it for several projects, including for [my other modules in CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~sharyanto).

The idea is you write your code in functions, decorate/add enough metadata to these functions (including some summary, specification of arguments, etc.) and there will be toolchains to take care of what you need, e.g. running your functions in the command-line (using [Sub::Spec::CmdLine](http://p3rl.org/Sub%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aCmdLine), and over HTTP (using [Sub::Spec::HTTP::Server](http://p3rl.org/Sub%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aHTTP%3a%3aServer) and [Sub::Spec::HTTP::Client](http://p3rl.org/Sub%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aHTTP%3a%3aClient)).

There is a [sample project](https://github.com/sharyanto/gudangapi/) in its infancy. Also take a look at http://gudangapi.com/. For example, the function [GudangAPI::API::finance::currency::id::bca::get_bca_exchange_rate()](https://github.com/sharyanto/gudangapi/blob/master/lib/perl/GudangAPI/API/finance/currency/id/bca.pm) will be accessible as an API function via HTTP API.

[Contact me](https://github.com/inbox/new/sharyanto) if you are interested in deploying something like this.

Comment: this seems to be completely in the way in which I want to move.  Have you found any other libraries like yours to do a comparison?

Comment: For writing command-line apps: If you use Moose, you can use [MooseX::Runnable](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Runnable). There's also [App::Cmd](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Cmd). As for exposing a function to HTTP, there's Plack/PSGI.