# How to dynamically load modules and execute methods in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336270) about perl web services.  I've managed to get modules loading and executing from a main program.  Each of the modules is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package NiMbox::perlet::skeleton;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(%DEFINITION main secondary);

our %DEFINITION;
$DEFINITION{'main'} = {
    summary => 'skeleton main',
    description => 'long skeleton main description',
    args => { 'box' => {}, 'other' => {} }
};
$DEFINITION{'secondary'} = {
    summary => 'skeleton secondary',
    description => 'long skeleton secondary description'
};

sub main {
    print "main...\n";
}

sub secondary {
    print "secondary...\n"
}

1;
```

And invocation of these modules can then be done like this:

```
use NiMbox::perlet::skeleton;

my %DEFINITION = %NiMbox::perlet::skeleton::DEFINITION;
foreach my $s (keys %DEFINITION) {
    print "calling sub '$s'\n";
    NiMbox::perlet::skeleton->$s();
}
```

How would I get rid of the direct invocation of `NiMbox::perlet:skeleton` in a way in which I could do something that looks like this (which does not work but illustrates what I need to do):

```
my $perlet = 'skeleton';

use NiMbox::perlet::$perlet;

my %DEFINITION = %NiMbox::perlet::$perlet::DEFINITION;
foreach my $s (keys %DEFINITION) {
    print "calling sub '$s'\n";
    NiMbox::perlet::$perlet->$s();
}
```

Since I'm very close I would rather see what is missing in this example rather than use another library.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) or its many follow on modules.  I see you're already using it in your module, but you're not using it to get `%DEFINITION`.  You'd do that like so:

```
use NiMbox::perlet::skeleton qw(%DEFINITION);

foreach my $s (keys %DEFINITION) {
    print "calling sub '$s'\n";
    NiMbox::perlet::skeleton->$s();
}
```

That aliases `%NiMbox::perlet::skeleton::DEFINITION` to `%DEFINITION` and saves a bunch of typing.

To be able to use a variable definition of `%DEFINITION` you could use "symbolic references" to refer to the variable by name... but those are fraught with peril.  Also, exporting global variables means you can only have one at a time in a given namespace.  We can do better.

What I would suggest is instead changing the `%DEFINITION` hash into the `definition()` class method which returns a reference to %DEFINITION.  You could return a hash, but the reference avoids wasting time copying.

```
package NiMbox::perlet::skeleton;

use strict;
use warnings;

my %DEFINITION = ...;

sub definition {
    return \%DEFINITION;
}
```

Now you can call that method and get the hash ref.

```
use NiMbox::perlet::skeleton;

my $definition = NiMbox::perlet::skeleton->definition;

foreach my $s (keys %$definition) {
    print "calling sub '$s'\n";
    NiMbox::perlet::skeleton->$s();
}
```

Doing it dynamically, the only trick is to load the class.  You can `eval "require $class" or die $@` but that has security implications.  [UNIVERSAL::require](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?UNIVERSAL%3a%3arequire) or [Module::Load](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aLoad) can handle that better for you.

```
use Module::Load;

my $class = 'NiMbox::perlet::skeleton';
load $class;

my $definition = $class->definition;

foreach my $s (keys %$definition) {
    print "calling sub '$s'\n";
    $class->$s();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such great explanation.  The only thing I would need to get rid off is the last `NiMbox::perlet::skeleton`.  In this way I can make the name of the module a variable and potentially call this like `docall skeleton main` which would invoke the `main` sub in the `skeleton` package.

Comment: Got it.  Just use `$class->$s()`.

Comment: @rmarimon Yes, that was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make the class name dynamic, you can do something like this:

```
my $class = 'NiMbox::perlet::' . $perlet;
my $class_file = $class;
$class_file =~ s{::}{/};
$class_file .= '.pm';

require $class_file;
$class->import;
```

(Or even better, use [Module::Load](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Module-Load/lib/Module/Load.pm) as [@Schwern suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525524/how-to-dynamically-load-modules-and-execute-methods-in-perl/6525677#6525677).

Getting the `%DEFINITION` class is a bit tricky since it would involve symbolic references. A better way would be to provide a class method that returns it, e.g.

```
package NiMbox::perlet::skeleton;
...
sub definition { 
    my %definition;
    $definition{main} = { summary => 'skeleton main', ... };
    return %definition;
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
my %DEFINITION = $class->definition;
foreach my $s( keys %DEFINITION ) { 
    print "calling sub '$s'\n";
    $class->$s;
}
```