# Perl: Dynamically loading modules and accessing the exported contents

Tags: perl, dynamic, module, load, package

After studying the Perl [require docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) and other links like this on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525524/how-to-dynamically-load-modules-and-execute-methods-in-perl) I'm still none the wiser, must be missing a fairly simple trick.  I'm loading a module at runtime and calling a subroutine in it.  The problem is I don't necessarily know the name of the exported subroutine, but there must be one and it is exported.

The modules all look like this, ie. they roughly follow a template taken from [perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=perlman:perlmod)

```
package modules::Test;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = (*TestSubSomeUnknownName);
@EXPORT_OK   = qw(&TestSubSomeUnknownName);
%EXPORT_TAGS = ( ALL => [qw(&TestSubSomeUnknownName)]
               );


sub TestSubSomeUnknownName
{
    # return a hash reference
}
```

Then I can access the sub like this, assuming I know its name:

```
use Module::Load;

my $package = "modules::Test";
my $subr = "TestSubSomeUnknownName";

load $package;
# Call the subroutine
my $hashref = $package->$subr;
```

But what if someone mis-spelled the name in a package or I don't know it?  The solution seems to be to use one of the EXPORTs to see what's in there, but how can it be done?

Comment: The official, current version of that Perlmonks document is at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `@EXPORT` should contain *names* not symbols.
- You don't need the ampersand before the function name and it's non standard.
- Remember the to return `1` at the end of a module.
- If you want to check what a package *can* do, use `can`.

  ```
  die 'Auto-import sub was not named "TestSubSomeUnknownName"' 
      unless  $package->can( 'TestSubSomeUnknownName' )
      ;
  $package->TestSubSomeUnknownName();
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can try what `@modules::Test::EXPORT` contains. Also, try running `$modules::Test::EXPORT[0]->()`;

Comment: +1  Why was this downvoted?  This is the only answer that approaches the question at hand.  (Granted, the original question a bit mushy — and the fact that the modules in question would @EXPORT what looks to be a class method is sadly wrong — but the OP is _not_ interested in a rehash of `perlmod`.)

Comment: This came pretty close to answering my question but it took a while to figure out how to remove the module name into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

- Writing a module and want to know how to export a subroutine?
- Are you looking at a module and want to use a subroutine from it?

For the answer to the first question, the answer is usually *Don't export anything automatically*. If you put a list of subroutine names under `@EXPORT_OK` list, you can export these subroutines using the following syntax in the main program:

```
 use My::Module qw(subroutines to be imported);
```

If you want to automatically import a subroutine, you can put it in the `@EXPORT` list. These will be automatically imported must the way `File::Copy` automatically imports the copy subroutine.

Now, modern Perl standards frown upon exporting anything because it *pollutes* the user's namespace without necessarily informing the user. If you really, really want to import something, the standard is now to use `@EXPORT_OK`, so the user has to list the subroutines they want to import in their `use` statement. This at least documents the pollution.

Some modern modules like `File::Spec` import nothing. You either have to prefix the subroutine  with the name of the module or use *object oriented* syntax (even if like `File::Spec`, it's not really object oriented because there are no objects to orient.)

Which brings us to another thing: Use Object Oriented Perl in your modules. Then, you don't have to worry about exporting anything because you don't in OOPerl.

If you're trying to do the second question and simply are trying to find the names of the subroutines from a third party module, use the `perldoc` command and see the documentation. You could look at `@EXPORT` and the `@EXPORT_OK` list to see what is exported, but there might be things that aren't exported (like the `$File::Find::Name` variable in the `File::Find` module) that might be important.

If you really want to get down and dirty, you can try going through each package variable like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

while (my ($var, $type) = each %Foo::) {
    if (defined &$type) {
        say "$var is a subroutine";
    }
    else {
        say "$var is defined as something or another";
    }
}

package Foo;

our %bar = (foo => 1, bar => 2);
our @foo = qw(foo bar);
our $fubar = "barfu";

sub barfu {
    print "FOO!";
    return "FOO!";
}
```

This will go through the package, show you what's defined, and even tell you if it's a subroutine or not. I get the following output:

```
barfu is a subroutine
fubar is defined as something or another
bar is defined as something or another
foo is defined as something or another
```

I wasn't able to figure out how to see what type of variable it is other than it's a defined subroutine. Maybe someone else can help me figure it out. I'd probably have to do something with `eval`.

---

## Modification w/ Thanks to Eric Storm

The following will show the type it is. Unfortunately, this will say everything is a scalar and a glob. Glob is understandable (it is a glob) but a scalar? I guess just leave these types out of the for loop for now.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

while (my ($var, $type) = each %Foo::) {
    print "$var";
#   foreach my $ref_type (qw(SCALAR GLOB ARRAY HASH CODE REF LVALUE FORMAT IO VSTRING Regexp)) {
    foreach my $ref_type (qw(ARRAY HASH CODE REF LVALUE FORMAT IO VSTRING Regexp)) {
        if (defined *$type{$ref_type}) {
            say qq("$var" is a type $ref_type);
        }
    }
}

package Foo;

our %bar = (foo => 1, bar => 2);
our @foo = qw(foo bar);
our $fubar = "barfu";

sub barfu {
    print "FOO!";
    return "FOO!";
}
```

Comment: Each `$type` is a glob reference, so `*$type{REF_TYPE}` to get at the references to each of the elements in the glob.

Comment: @EricStrom - Thanks, I modified my code to search for all the various types according to `perldoc -f ref` has. It points out subroutine (CODE), HASH, and ARRAY very nicely. However, each one is also a reference to a SCALAR and a GLOB. I understand GLOB, but why SCALAR?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I return to this question - perhaps I was a bit vague but the problem I have is to dynamically load modules, and find out what's exported from these modules by looking at the dynamically loaded module only.

After a bit of hacking the following works for the purpose:

```
my $package = 'modules::Test';
load $package;
my $exports; 
eval {
    no strict;
    $exports = \@{"$package\::EXPORT"};
};
# Call the subroutine
my $subr = @{$exports}[0];
my $hash = $package->$subr if($package->can($subr));
```

The name of the package to load is just a string, the package is loaded, the $exports line (copied from Exporter.pm that I found single stepping a [$_->import](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=313810)) returns the list of exported symbols and I can then call the first one.

If someone can improve this still further I'm interested.